# Can you help deconstruct this SFX?

Tags: sfx, replication, analysis

I'm struggling to figure out how to recreate a specific sound effect.
It's the prize bubble collection noise from the video game LittleBigPlanet 3. There are several varieties but a cohesive overall design.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

- Around the the 12:25 mark are some examples

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. Ive had some good luck with vintage camera flashes, the finger in the mouth 'pop', fireworks, plastic bottles and running things along ridged surfaces. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a combination of a short hit sound and a long water splash sound. Maybe a little paper wrinkling noise can be added.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...tricky. I'd say something like a wet pair of jeans smashed against the floor together with squeezing a balloon, all with a lot of compressor.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a bubble pop noise like when you stick your finger in your mouth and pop it out... Then use a crinkled paper noise. They also have crow noises with each bubble pop. The crow noises have been pitch shifted a little as they progress to a slightly higher pitch each time.